# Obj-C to Swift conversion (inc. Cocoapods)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, cocoapods

Started with an Objective-C and Swift mixed project...

Gradually I have converted all of the code over to Swift. Quite happy about that.

I've now turned my attention to all Cocoapod dependencies, and all the obvious ones have been either removed or swapped for Swift equivalents...

However, I am using Google Firebase Cocoapods (Objective-C) and cannot find a Swift alternative for it.
(I'm using Firebase for app analytics and help with push notifications)
Am I missing a trick here? Is there a good alternative for Firebase that is 100% Swift?

I know some may suggest I just keep Firebase in Obj-C, but my thinking is if I can 100% convert my project over to Swift I will be future-proofing it for a good few years.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Swift alternative"? An Objective-C SDK can be used from Swift, so I'm not exactly sure what your goal is – do you care whether a third-party framewor you use is internally implemented in Swift or not? Do you care about the "Swiftiness" of the API?

Comment: Swift alternative, as in a Cocoapod dependencies which does near enough the same job as the current (Firebase) but all code is written in Swift. No Obj-C.

Comment: I still don't understand your motivation: why does it matter if a library you use is implemented in Obj-C or Swift as long as you can use it from Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn’t have a pure Swift SDK. I don’t think Google cares enough about iOS dependancies.

Also, technically if you’re looking to change proof iOS code, ObjC is “better” because unlike Swift it has no versioning.
But! I can’t recommend anyone to write a project in ObjC just because it might require less code maintenance.

Comment: That makes sense. I get what you are saying. It’s just... I have a feeling Obj-C will eventually become obsolete and not accepted in uploads for the Appstore. I only say this because that’s what Apple do. They promote a new technology (HTML5, USB-C, Thunderbolt), and they shun old technologies (Flash, Headphone jack etc.) You might think i’m wrong but I prefer to have my codebase 100% Swift including all cocoapod dependencies.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I 100% agree with you on Swift. I worked with ObjC in the past and prefer to avoid it. But sadly, ObjC is not going anywhere, not even in 5 years, since a major part of Apple’s APIs are still written in ObjC, and since Swift 2 I didn’t notice too much change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems when working in iOS 14 with Firebase pods. I ended up figuring out that the issue was only coming  from the general 'Firebase' pod.

Basically, DON'T use:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

And use the specific pods instead:

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
```

When you import frameworks to a file, import the specific pod. (ie. "import FirebaseCore" and not "import Firebase").  I would assume Google will eventually update the general pod to be compatible.

Comment: It's fine to use `pod 'Firebase'`. There was a bug that was fixed in the 6.31.1 release. See 
 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6341

Comment: Oh that's great news. Cheers